# Architecture for syncing s3/cloudfront with database

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, synchronization, amazon-cloudfront

I'm building a Django app. The app allows the user to upload files, and have them served publicly to other users.

I'm thinking of using S3 or CloudFront to manage and serve these files. (Let's call it S3 for the sake of discussion.) What bugs me is the fact that S3 is going to have a lot of state on it. My Python code will create, rename and delete files on S3 based on user actions. But we already have all the state in our database. Having state in two separate datastores could lead to synchronization problems and confusing. In other words it's "not supposed to" go out of sync. For example if someone were to delete a record in the database from the django admin, the file on s3 will stay orphaned. (I could write code to deal with that scenario, but I can't catch all the scenarios.)

So what I'm thinking is: Is there a solution for having your S3 sync automatically with data in your Postgres database? (I have no problem storing the files as blobs in the database, they're not big, as long as they're not served directly from there.) I'm talking about having an active program that always maintains sync between them, so if say someone deletes a record in the database, the corresponding file in s3 gets deleted, and if someone deletes a file from the S3 interface, it gets recreated from the database. That way my mind could rest at ease regarding synchronization issues.

Is there something like that? Most preferably in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Found the same problem in the past, maybe not the best advice but here's what I did.

I wrote the upload/modify/remove to S3 logic in the models and used [Model signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals) to keep it updated, for example you can use the `post_delete` signal to delete the image from S3 and avoid orphans.

Also I had a management command to check if everything is synchronized and solve the problems if any. Unfortunately I wrote this for a client and I cannot share it.

Edit: I found [django-cb-storage-s3](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/django-mediasync) and [django-s3sync](https://github.com/pcraciunoiu/django-s3sync) they could be helpful

Comment: I looked at your two packages. The first one looks like it was intended for static rather than media files (despite its name) and  it hasn't been updated in any way, and the second one looks abandoned. The solution you proposed in your answer might work... But still I'm hoping for a package I could use.